# Using [NSString stringWithFormat] in UITAbleViewCell displaying as empty string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I must be missing something basic here. When I use `[NSString stringWithFormat]` to set a property of an object that displays in a **UITableViewCell**, it displays as empty. If I just set the property normally, i.e. `property = @"Item One"`, it displays fine. The code, and result below.

**Using this:**
[image]

**Results in:**

[image]

**Yet the log shows:**
[image]

Which would indicate the property is set. Will someone please take me to school here.

**EDIT**
Underretaining was the issue.

My prop looked as such: `@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *name`

Changing that to: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name`

Fixed the issue. I understand that this means I retain a strong reference to this property, but in this particular, **is there a "I just graduated college and taught himself Obj-C" explanation as to what was happening in memory to cause this issue?**

Comment: My first thought, since a constant string works, is that you're under-retaining the `name` property, although if that's true I'm surprised you aren't crashing.

Comment: Show the code where you populate the label.

Comment: @KevinBallard If you submit your comment as the answer, I would be happy to accept it since you were indeed correct.

Comment: -1 for not showing the relevant code.

Comment: @HotLicks -1 for not reading my edit with the relevant code.

Comment: No, you still haven't shown all the relevant code.  We have no idea how the value jumps from your structure to the label.  And you only edited in (what you call) the "relevant code" after it was suggested what the problem was.

Comment: @J-MANMORGAN: Submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought, since a constant string works, is that you're under-retaining the name property, although if that's true I'm surprised you aren't crashing.

**Edit:**

After seeing your code, here's the problem. A `weak` property only holds a value as long as the value is kept alive elsewhere. A constant string lives forever, so assigning a constant string here worked. But if you assign a calculated value, then nothing owns it, and therefore nothing keeps it alive, and therefore your weak property will end up with `nil`.

Comment: Awesome, great answer/explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're assigning `name` to the `text` property of a UILabel.

Either the label is:

1. nil
2. Hidden (check it's hidden property)
3. not in the view hierarchy (check it's superview property)
4. Not big enough to show the text (calling `sizeToFit` will fix this)
5. The same color as your background (not likely)

The hardest problem to solve will be if it is nil. You haven't told us where the cell is coming from but here are a few possibilities.

1. The IBOutlet isn't set in the xib/storyboard
2. You aren't instantiating it in the correct `init` method. If you are instantiating it, make sure that specific init variation is being called.

Comment: Hey Lance, thanks for all of your suggestions. See my above edit.